# Mystery with ArrayList<Object> in a HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap, setter, getter

I am just running the below code and I am surprised with the results. Can someone explain me whats happening here?
My question is.. when I set a value using an object setter into a new copy of original arraylist, why is the object value in the original arrayList also getting changed?

Please let me know if I am doing anything wrong here.

```
public class TestHashMap {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    HashMap<String, ArrayList<ResultData>> hmData = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<ResultData>>();
    ArrayList<ResultData>  arrData = new ArrayList<ResultData>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        ResultData rData = new ResultData();
        rData.setDy(i + 1);
        arrData.add(rData);
    }
    hmData.put("test",arrData);
    System.out.println("Before >>>> "+hmData.get("test").get(1).getDy());
    ArrayList<ResultData> newList = new ArrayList<ResultData>();
    newList = hmData.get("test");
    ResultData rNew = newList.get(1);
    rNew.setDy(1234566);
    System.out.println("##### >>>>> "+arrData.get(1).getDy());
    System.out.println("After >>>> "+hmData.get("test").get(1).getDy());  
}}
```

Comment: Image is not clear. It would be better if you could provide the code and desired output in text

Comment: There's definitely something wrong here because you do `newList = new ArrayList<ResultData>()` and then immediately `newList = hmData.get("test")`. What was the point of creating the second list?

Comment: Added the code.. and below is the output

Before >>>> 2.0
##### >>>>> 1234566.0
After >>>> 1234566.0

Comment: Please also edit your question to explain what you thought should happen, and how that's different to what actually happened.

Comment: @kaya3 , yes I took a copy of the content in hashmap into the variable newList and updating an object value in that newList using object setter.

Comment: My intended output should be:

Before >>>> 2.0
##### >>>>> 2.0
After >>>> 2.0

Comment: Are you aware that your code does not actually use two lists? I think there are multiple levels of confusion here.

Comment: `newList = hmData.get("test")` is **not** creating a new list, its just using the  reference to the existing one; same for `rNew = newList.get(1);` at the end you are changing the original instance which itself is still in the original list (it wouldn't make any difference if the list was a new one, unless also a new `ResultData` was created)

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger, Ok. So, can you suggest me a way to modify an element in the arraylist without modifying the original arraylist in hashmap?

Comment: make a (real) copy of the map instance - `new HashMap(hmData)` (eventually also from its content, that is, a deep copy, otherwise you will be changing the original `ResultData`, which **will** also be reflected in original map)

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger, thank you. Let me try that and will let you know the results.

Comment: CarlosHeuberger Thank you so much. You are right. making a deep copy/clone of the original hashmap worked.

Answer (score 0):

Reason: You are referring to the same old object, with the new reference. (Stored in hmData).
So at the object level, they both refer to the same Object memory location in Heap, that why changing one value is reflecting in another.

Little more Explanation:
Let's assume arrData is stored at "A" Memory Location. When you get the value against key = "test" and storing it in newList using code "newList = hmData.get("test");", values are retrieved from A memory location only (Only reference variable is changing -Stack Memory).
When you change the value of the object stored in newList, value is altered for A memory location, which is used by both the lists (arrData and newList)

Answer (score 0):

Like **Aayush Sethi** said the object you retrieved from hmData.get("test")

```
newList = hmData.get("test");

ResultData rNew = newList.get(1);
```

is the same under TWO names: newList and rNew. If you want to have different objects with the same content you have to clone it (whereas ResultData should be an implementation of **Cloneable**)